# Как добавлять в корзину товары с помощью ajax?

Tags: php, woocommerce

Подскажите, как настроить добавление товара в корзину с помощью ajax?
В магазине на основе плагина woocommerce используются стандартные шаблоны на всех страницах, а именно archive-product.php и для вывода товара content-product.php.
Других плагинов не установлено! В шапке есть такой код, который показывает количество товаров в корзине:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js">
<head>
    <title><?php wp_title();?> | <?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

<div class="top-cart">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo wc_get_cart_url(); ?>">
                <span class="cart-icon"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></span>
                <span class="cart-total">
                    <span class="cart-title"><?php _e( 'Cart', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span>
                    <span class="cart-item"><?php echo sprintf ( _n( '%d item', '%d items', WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ), WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ); ?>- </span>
                    <span class="top-cart-price"><?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_total(); ?></span>
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

При нажатии на кнопку "Добавить в корзину" на одном из товаров, этот товар добавляется в корзину, но в шапке это изменение не видно. А если перезагрузить страницу, тогда в шапке видно, что количество товаров прибавилось на единицу.
Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на "Добавить в корзину" в шапке было сразу видно, что количество увеличилось на один товар с помощью ajax?
Нужно ли что-то прописывать в файле functions.php для ajax?

Comment: у кого какие идеи? Есть какие-то предположения или нет?

Comment: Так кто-то подскажет по данному вопросу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть плагин - [WooCommerce Menu Cart](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-menu-bar-cart/). Проще всего убрать свой код из шапки и использовать этот плагин.

Comment: а есть плагин, чтобы корзина установилась с нужными стилями, соответствующими стилям темы?

Comment: Нет, конечно. Потому что никто не знает, какие там стили у темы.

Comment: в этом плагине нельзя расположить корзину в нужном месте и с нужными стилями

Comment: а смысл тогда в этом плагине?

Comment: Все можно - правьте css на здоровье.

Comment: его можно установить только в меню. А как установить в шапку?

Comment: Смысл в том, что плагин выводит корзину, в которую идет добавление по ajax. То есть, он делает ровно то, о чем был задан вопрос. Если же вам еще и стили поправить, то надо обратиться на фриланс.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56356/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-word).

Comment: Вот прежде чем задавать миллион вопросов, потрудитесь хоть что-то прочитать из того, что вам советуют. Откройте страницу плагина и найдите там: Shortcode to display cart anywhere on your site

Comment: я что-то не нашёл страницу документации по шорткодам

Comment: >потрудитесь хоть что-то прочитать из того, что вам советуют

Comment: где можно почитать?

Comment: там вообще нет ничего про шорткоды

Comment: кстати благодарю за плагин! Узнал из него много интересного.

Comment: >Проще всего убрать свой код из шапки и использовать этот плагин.

Comment: Согласен, что это сделать проще всего. Но иногда этого не позволяет вёрстка. Пришлось лезть в код плагина

Answer (score 1):

Может кому пригодится:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'woocommerce_header_add_to_cart_fragment' );
function woocommerce_header_add_to_cart_fragment( $fragments ) {
    ob_start(); ?>
    <a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo wc_get_cart_url(); ?>" title="<?php _e( 'View your shopping cart' ); ?>"><?php echo sprintf (_n( '%d item', '%d items', WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ), WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ); ?> - <?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_total(); ?></a>
    <?php
    $fragments['a.cart-contents'] = ob_get_clean();
    return $fragments;
}
```